# Embedded Excel Spreadsheet with formulas. Round up/down of values not copied across?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

[image]So I have created an Excel with calculation formulas and embedded it into a HTML page using an Excel add-in. It works successfully in the HTML page but the rounding up and down of figures in the spreadsheet has not copied across to the HTML. Have attached a pic of what has been pasted into the HTML. From what I can tell, being a novice Javascript guy, it is supposedly using the math.round already?

Any support on this would be amazing!

Thanks in advance.

Joe

Comment: "using an Excel add-in" - might want to be a little more specific about this part.  Also there doesn't seem to be any attached image.

Comment: Apologies Tim, Image now uploaded. the excel add-in was called excel2html, a plug in. Took a risk and downloaded it from a random.